# Navigation category - how to get a collection?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, custom, navigation

How can I get a collection of the categories and subcategories to build custom navigation ?

```
$_categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');

$i;

echo '<div class="navigation">';

foreach($_categories as $_category){

    echo '<ul class="category">';

    echo $i. '<li>'. $_category->getName().'</li>';$i++;

    echo $categoryId = $_category->getId();

    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

//$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(228);

    $subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    if (count($subcategories) > 0){

        echo $_category->getName();

        foreach($subcategories as $id){

            echo $name = $id->getName().'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</div>';`
```

It actually is giving me a full list of categories including all those I don't need ;)
Should I pull all categories from products ?

Comment: Please add details which categories you don't want in your collection

Comment: Actually i would like to have all categories and sub categories then i will seletcively show/hide what i want to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select sub categories based on categorie id also. If You need i can give you code also .

// here is the code

```
<?php 

$parentCategoryId = 222;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

// Get 1 Level sub category of Parent category
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
              {
                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a><li>';

  }
}
*/
?>
```

Comment: Hello Saurabh, would be very nice. However I was doing it, just because collection contains all categories including brands, events etc not just products ... my menu is like 800 buttons :) and I don't know how to filter it :)

Comment: <?php 
$parentCategoryId = 222; // change to your main cat id 
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

// Get 1 Level sub category of Parent category
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
              {
                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a><li>';
  
  }
}
*/
?>

Comment: Aaaaaa it's obvious! Silly me. You are 100% right, this is it!. I should read only a root for this range of categories what in result will give me an array with ids I'm looking for ;) Right ? :)

Comment: Yes brother ! You can fetch $_category as you want .